# mass email with phpmailer

Tags: php, phpmailer

i'm new to PHPMAILER
and i want to send about 200 email from text file not sql db,
i'm using the normal example in github

```
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

//Load composer's autoloader
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer(true);                              // Passing `true` enables exceptions
try {
    //Server settings
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 1;                                 // Enable verbose debug output
    $mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
    $mail->Host = 'server';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Username = 'user';                 // SMTP username
    $mail->Password = 'fbzA2qMk2pNn';                           // SMTP password
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
    $mail->Port = 587;                                    // TCP port to connect to
  $mail->setFrom('test@test.com', 'test');

$mail->addAddress('email@email.com'); 
  etc
```

how i can add about 200/1000 email to  addAddress() ?

Comment: _"how i can add about 200/1000 email to addAddress()"_ Don't do that. Put the code in a loop and send 200 separate emails.

Comment: @AlexHowansky gives me error do you can explain with code ?

Comment: Try looking just *a little* bit further at [the mailing list example provided with PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/mailing_list.phps).

Comment: There's also [a wiki page all about sending to lists efficiently](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Sending-to-lists) with PHPMailer.

Comment: i don't want to use sql

Comment: i think iwill try to split it and turn to arrays